# relation between boys and girls

Tags: islamic-philosophy

I love a girl and I want to meet her.but Islam forbad me to meet her but I think it is so necessory to meet her for my upcoming life. 
I don't have any negative approach regarding her. 
Can I meet her??

Comment: Maybe my Answer here could help http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25940/can-a-woman-make-an-unknown-person-her-brother-and-share-her-life-story-with-him/25973#25973

Comment: Till you didn't any thing wrong about touch her, don't annoy yourself with these thoughts. Live free.

Answer (score 1):

To tell you the truth, I would say no.

You shouldn't approach her even though you think you don't have any negative intention unless you are married.

> Ibn 'Umar (Radhiallaahu Ta'ala anhu) narrated:
>
> > " 'Umar delivered a Khutbah to us at Al-Jabiyah. He said: 'O you people! Indeed I have stood among you as the Messenger of Allah(s.a.w) stood among us, and he said: "I order you (to stick to) my Companions, then those who come after them, then those who come after them. Then lying will spread until a man will take an oath when no oath was sought from him, and a witness will testify when his testimony was not sought. **`Behold! A man is not alone with a woman but the third of them is Ash-Shaitan.`** Adhere to the Jama'ah, beware of separation, for indeed Ash-Shaitan is with one, and he is further away from two. Whoever wants the best place in Paradise, then let him stick to the Jama'ah. Whoever rejoices with his good deeds and grieves over his evil deeds, then that is the believer among you.'"
> >
> > > Jami` at-Tirmidhi 2165