# Who can be a chaperone when talking to a potential woman?

Tags: nikah, relationships, men-women, mahram

I would like to know who can be a chaperone when you want to get to know a potential woman? For the purposes of marriage of course.

Can a friend of the woman be a sufficient chaperone?

Please offer citations/sources in the answers.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider taking your time to learn more about this site and the stack exchange model by taking our 2 min. [tour] and visiting our [help].

Comment: This can be done by a mahram this is any person she can't get married with like her brother, father etc. (in first place)

Comment: @Medi1Saif Thanks for the comment, are you saying only relatives and not woman friends? Do you have a source/link for this so I can further read.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25940/can-a-woman-make-an-unknown-person-her-brother-and-share-her-life-story-with-him see also http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28470/relation-between-boys-and-girls?noredirect=1&lq=1 and I'm quite sure there are other posts on the matter.