# Are we allowed to have friends of the opposite gender?

Tags: nikah, relationships

I stopped my wife from having male friends online and also because of this I blocked all those people from her Facebook account. And whenever she talks to male friends I check her conversation and complain when I see something I don't like.

She says this is controlling and I have trust issues. Is her having a male friend allowed in Islam? Is me controlling her like this allowed in Islam?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. COnsider taking our [tour] and checking our [help] to learn more about our site and model. Here a related post [Can a woman make an unknown person her brother and share her life story with him?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25940/can-a-woman-make-an-unknown-person-her-brother-and-share-her-life-story-with-him) and [Does the Quran and Sunnah directly forbid male-female interaction aside from sex?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8185/does-the-quran-or-sunnah-directly-forbid-male-female-interactions-aside-from-se)

Answer (score -1):

In Islam, its not permissible for a married couple to have friends of the opposite gender. Interactions are okay, friendship is not. If you are not married, then you can be friends with whoever you want. So technically, she's not allowed to have any male friends (assuming that she's muslim too) and you have every right asking her to stop. Yes it does have to do with trust issues because Allah doesn't trust us so he forbade us to go anywhere near it so that we're protected.

Answer (score -2):

No person is allowed to have friends of the opposite gender. Is it because of trust issues? Yes. Allah does not trust us. In fact, he does not trust us so much (especially in this matter) he doesn't allow us to go anywhere near Zina:

> Do not even go close to Zina. It is indeed an indecency and an evil way. (17:32)

Having 'friends' of the opposite gender is definitely not allowed due to the above ayah and other ayah from the Quran. Please note, we are allowed to speak to the opposite gender while keeping a respectful distance and language in a public setting. Online conversation are not in a public setting and are thhus not allowed.

The husband completely has the right to demand his wife not speak privately online with other males, as does the wife have a right to demand the husband not speak to females.

Comment: In my opinion, it is allowed, but if two best friends, a girl and a boy together, they are just friends, but don’t go to Adultery then, everything is fine, but is they go to Adultery, then it becomes prohibited their friendship. And they should find friends of their gender.

Answer (score -2):

For me, it depends if a man and woman are allowed to be friends. If you intentionally have feelings for/flirt with him/her, then obviously that is haram, also there shouldn't be body contact either. If you personally know that what you're doing is wrong then it will be your consequence for the after life especially. But I wouldn't just be alone with him/her, unless I'd get permission off my parents.